# How can i get a springboot project like “start.spring.io” by myself

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I use https://start.spring.io/ to get a `springboot` project, I just input `Group` `Artifact` and click the `Generate Project` button, then  I get a empty `springboot` project.

But I want to know, when I click  the `Generate Project` button, What did it do on the server? In other words, if I want to get a `springboot` project by myself, what should I do?

I know to use the `mvn` to get a `springmvc` project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.spring -DartifactId=SpringMVC -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractivMode=false -DarchetypeCatalog=internal
```

Then it gives me `pom.xml`, `src/`. But the `springboot` project has `mvnw`, `mvnw.cmd`, `.mvn`, I don't know how to get the files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So concretely there is an endpoint that takes the form that `start.spring.io` provides (called `ProjectRequest`). Based on these settings, `ProjectGenerator` is invoked. This will create a project in a temporary directory with the following:

- A build file (`pom.xml` for Maven or `build.gradle` for Gradle)
- A wrapper for the build (again Maven or Gradle, depending on the `project-type` parameter that is materialized by a drop down list at the top of the UI)
- A simple class for the application
- A simple test for the application
- An empty configuration file (`application.properties`).

`ProjectGenerator` can also react to certain choices. For instance, if a web application is requested (because it has the "web" facet), a `templates` and `static` directories are created for views and static assets respectively.

Files are created using Mustache templates.

If you want to know more about how this works, check the [source code](https://github.com/spring-io/initializr) and the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

Answer (score 0):

`mvnw`, `mvnw.cmd` are files that come form [`Maven Wrapper project`](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper). The data in the `pom.xml` is filled as a template based on your selection of the dependencies. Spring does not provide a direct `archetype:generate` command for generating a `Spring boot` project. Even IDEs like `STS` and `Intelij` depend on the Spring boot starter website for generating projects. The use of Maven wrapper enables the users to download correct dependencies even if maven is not on the path or installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

To manually create a spring boot project please follow below steps :

1. create a new maven project in eclipse or any IDE you are using
2. add below dependency in pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
   ```

Comment: for more details you can refer the below article which describes all three ways to start spring boot project
https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-spring-boot-project-with-eclipse-and-ma